# How to stop Type 13 mismatch for VBA code when deleting a row in a table?

Tags: excel, vba

The idea is that when an update is made to each of the steps in the dropdown, a timestamp gets logged so I can have a sense of how long each step took. The problem I am having is that if a row is deleted (which happens) I get the Type 13 mismatch code and the code stops running. How do I prevent this from happening?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim intersectRange1 As Range

    ' Column O
    Set rng1 = Range("R:R")
    Set intersectRange1 = Intersect(Target, rng1)

    If Not intersectRange1 Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If intersectRange1.Validation.Type = 3 Then
            If Target.Value = "Pending Reqs" Or Target.Value = "Reqs Received" Or Target.Value = "Approved" Then
                Debug.Print "Column O Change Detected"
                Select Case Target.Value
                    Case "Pending Reqs"
                        If Cells(Target.Row, "AO").Value = "" Then
                            Cells(Target.Row, "AO").Value = Now
                        Else: Cells(Target.Row, "AO").Value = Cells(Target.Row, "AO").Value & ", " & Now
                        End If
                    Case "Reqs Received"
                        If Cells(Target.Row, "AP").Value = "" Then
                            Cells(Target.Row, "AP").Value = Now
                        Else: Cells(Target.Row, "AP").Value = Cells(Target.Row, "AP").Value & ", " & Now
                        End If
                    Case "Approved"
                        If Cells(Target.Row, "AQ").Value = "" Then
                            Cells(Target.Row, "AQ").Value = Now
                        Else: Cells(Target.Row, "AQ").Value = Cells(Target.Row, "AQ").Value & ", " & Now
                        End If
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    End If

Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

I tried disabling the error and let the code run in spite of errors but this didn't seem to work either.

Comment: `If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub`.

Answer (score -1):

So the problem is your code stops running when a row is missing

The solution is to skip that row, here is how:
Check if there is a blank cell and delete them by looping through your desired range

````
   set SelectedRange = R:R 'you can change this to your preference
   for each cell in SelectedRange
   if isempty(cell) then
              cell.delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
   end if
next cell```
````